# Spring controller method access control without Spring Security

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm looking for a way to control access to a URI by IP addresses without using Spring Security. Should I use an filter or interceptor?

An idea?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean you are using spring security and you want some URL's to be excluded from being secured?

Comment: No, I'm not using Spring Security and looking for a simple way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it pretty easy with a Tomcat RemoteAddrFilter.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Remote Address Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteAddrFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>allow</param-name>
        <param-value>[my ip address regex]</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Remote Address Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/config/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```